# How to make icon and its label clickable in aura component

Tags: aura

I was writing an logic for button and text which need to be clickable. on click of image its navigating to community page correctly. but on click of the text it was not navigating to the community page. Could some one help out with any suggestions.
Below is the code that i wrote.
[image]

```
<li id="myid" data-menuid="Mydiv1" onclick="{!c.navigationlogic}">
    <a href="#" title="sample text">
        <i class="ownclassimage usericonsample"></i>
        <span>sample text</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

### helper logic navigationlogic:

```
navigationlogic  : function(component, event, helper) {
   debugger;
    sessionStorage.setItem('filteredTerm', '');
    const nav = document.querySelectorAll(".active"); 
    for (var i = 0; i <nav.length; i++){
        nav[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    var selectedItem = event.currentTarget.dataset.menuid;
    var pagename;
  
    if(selectedItem == 'sometext'){
        document.getElementById("colbar").style.setProperty('display', 'none');
        document.getElementById("mymenu").style.setProperty('display', 'block');
        document.getElementById("sidenav").style.setProperty('display', 'none');
        document.querySelector("#myId #my1ub").classList.add("active");
        pagename= 'randompage';
        if(component.get("v.user")){
            if(component.get("v.user").country.toLowerCase()=='somecountry'){
                pagename = 'randompage';
            }
        }
    }
    
    var navService = component.find( "navService" );  
    var pageReference = {  
        type: "comm__namedPage",  
        attributes: {  
            pageName: pagename
        }
    };  
    navService.navigate(pageReference); 
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
},
```

Comment: could someone give me some idea pls

Comment: Please post your code as code, not as an image. This makes it more difficult for someone to investigate your problem.

Comment: i posted it as code but it was not taking html characters .

Comment: <li id="myid" data-menuid="Mydiv1" onclick="{!c.navigationlogic}"> 
<a href="#" title="sample text">
<i class="ownclassimage usericonsample"></i>
<span>sample text</span>
</a>
</li>

Comment: @dileep Can you also share `navigationlogic` code snippet?

Comment: @NagendraSingh added navigationlogic code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try `<i class="ownclassimage usericonsample">sample text</i>`

Comment: tried that way but did not worked @ JPM